# Running Composer inside Docker container as host user

Tags: docker, composer-php

I faced with a rather strange Docker Composer-related issue. The point is that the Composer being ran onto different PHP versions installs different versions of sources. In my particular case project's `composer.json` has `"doctrine/orm":"2.5"` required which in its turn is declared as [PHP 5 compatible](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm#v2.5.14) . And if I ran `composer install` on local PHP 7 CLI interpreter it installs PHP7-only compatible version of code tree and I got a lot of E_PARSE since Doctrine code has class constants visibility modifiers and function return types. If I run `composer install` inside my `php:5-apache-jessie`-based container everything is OK (except some issues below) and the project runs successfully.

OK then, seems we should not use local interpreter to have correct sources in the project. Let's make it run composer inside the container. When I ran it manually there is a warning about not running Composer as root and we have a root-owned directory that is not good. If we exec into container we still can not run something like `sudo -u www-data -c 'composer install'` since `www-data` user has no login. I can't just add `RUN composer install` as I don't have volume mounted at the moment building the image while running it with `docker-compose`.

I think ideal situation we could run all the container commands as host user. But when I tried to use `USER` directive in Dockerfile setting it to my UID, container just even did not start.

So, the question is: what is workflow one should use to have correct (means related to actual server environment) version of Composer dependencies while running PHP project inside Docker container?